# I just want to make A simple loop in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, for-loop

In the PostGIS SQL Editor, I just want to make a loop to make this function work

```
For Loopid = 0 to 1000, then execute the following statments:

UPDATE public.globaldtm 
SET "UTM" = loopid 
WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
```

[image]

How to write a simple code inside this SQL editor to make the loop work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the set-returning [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) function in the optional `FROM` clause of a [update statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE public.globaldtm 
SET UTM = loopid
FROM generate_series(0, 1000) as x(loopid) -- Added this line
WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
```

This is your query, with the addition of this line:

```
FROM generate_series(0, 1000) as x(loopid)
```

---

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c9ce2/2) of a similar, simplified query.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, thank you a lot. I didn't expect someone can give me an answer during the weekend. And by the way, I still want to learn the PostgreSQL from the basics. During my work, I am feeling that I have to keep finishing the project so no time for learning the basics. I want to learn it after work, do you have some recommendation ?

Comment: By the way, SET "UTM" = loopid, will this loopid also be updated through the loop?

Comment: Yes it does. I've added a demo link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateValuesWithLoop()
RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR Loopid  IN 0..1000 LOOP
    UPDATE public.globaldtm 
       SET "UTM" = loopid 
     WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Execute the function:

```
select updateValuesWithLoop()
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, using a PL/PgSQL function should generally be a last resort as a loop in PL/PgSQL performs *much* worse than doing the same thing in a single query as a join over `generate_series` or similar. I've upvoted you, but in future it's really best to explain a bit more.